# using group_concat in PHPMYADMIN will show the result as [BLOB - 3B]

Tags: mysql, casting, phpmyadmin, group-by, group-concat

I have a query which uses the GROUP_CONCAT of mysql on an integer field.
I am using PHPMYADMIN to develop this query. My problem that instead of showing 1,2 which is the result of the concatenated field, I get [BLOB - 3B].

Query is

```
SELECT rec_id,GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)
FROM t1
GROUP BY rec_id
```

(both fields are unsigned int, both are not unique)

What should I add to see the actual results?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just above the query result (to the left) you will see `+options`. Press it and mark

> Show BLOB contents

> Full texts

[image]

Comment: Just to help out users who can't see the `+options`, not all configurations of phpmyadmin have it

Answer (score 89):

Looks as though GROUP_CONCAT expects that value to be a string. I just ran into the same problem. Solved it by converting the int column to a string like so:

```
SELECT rec_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(user_id, CHAR(8)))
FROM t1
GROUP BY rec_id
```

Figured I'd share in case you were still having an issue with this.

Answer (score 46):

[According to the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), `CAST(expr AS type)` is standard SQL and should thus be perferred. Also, you may omit the string length. Therefore, I’d suggest the following:

```
SELECT rec_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(user_id AS CHAR))
FROM t1
GROUP BY rec_id
```

Answer (score 23):

For me, this helped (found it in this [blog post](http://www.mike250.com/blog/2010/26/05/mysql-group_concat-returns-blob-14-b)):

In my case the parameter to `GROUP_CONCAT` was string but the function still resulted in a BLOB, but converting the result of the `GROUP_CONCAT` worked.

```
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) USING 'utf8')
```

Comment: I want to hug you and kick the guy who designed the database I am using for using 'latin1' encoding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 512;
```

If group_concat_max_len is more than 512 the query will return byte[].
But you can pass to a string.

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString((byte[])DataTable.Rows[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

*In the latest Phpmyadmin*

After running query, you will see some results and then dot ..

so just click on **options** (which is on top of the query result)

Then Just select

> Full texts

radio button, default is **Partial texts**

Then press **Go** button and you will see full result

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the `config.inc.php` file in the phpMyAdmin directory, then 
I think the best solution is to change this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
```

to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

If you have the mysqli extension available, use it. It is more secure, a bit more optimized, and it handles the BLOB type of utf-8 better by default. Your [BLOB] entries should start showing up as their values without having to add in any other special configuration options.