# mysql sum, with row IDs

Tags: mysql, sum

In MySQL I'm trying to sum up a column but retain the row IDs. When I do a sum, the IDs are compressed and the result is

1 | 1500

What I would like is

1,2,3 | 1500

Comment: is their any problem if sum repeated no. of times the rows exists.

Comment: Just change `id` to `DISTINCT id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), SUM(value) FROM table`

Comment: Thanks. I had to use `GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(id AS CHAR))` or else I get a BLOB in the result...

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Out of curiosity, what data type is your `id` column?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), SUM(column_name) FROM table_name GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I'm getting a [BLOB - 5B] under the GROUP_CONCAT column. Found from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133936/using-group-concat-in-phpmyadmin-will-show-the-result-as-blob-3b that GROUP_CONCAT expects value to be a string. Any issues with using `GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(id AS CHAR))` ?