# SQL: Add all data from related table to a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have these two simple tables:

Invoices:
 ID          Date        ...
  1      1/1/2011
  2      1/2/2011

Invoice_Products:
  invoiceId     productId       Quantity
       1                            101                 1000
       1                            200                       50
       1                            310                    125
       2                            101                 2000
       2                            222                 1000

I want a select query that will have the following result:

invoiceId         date           sumProducts
       1                 1/1/2011       101,200,310
       2                 1/2/2011                  101,222

my problem is how to add the result of the select query to invoice_Products table to a single column comma delimeted.

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance...

Comment: just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802900/mysql-sum-with-row-ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. Something like this:

```
SELECT  Invoice_Products.invoiceId,
        Invoices.Date,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Invoice_Products.productId) AS productIds
  FROM Invoice_Products
  JOIN Invoices ON Invoice_Products.invoiceId = Invoices.ID
 GROUP BY invoiceId
;
```

[See the result here.](http://sqlize.com/lN7qaONE2v)

Answer (score 0):

TRY this.

```
SELECT invoiceID,DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m/%d/%Y') as `DATE`,GROUP_CONCAT(PRODUCTID) as `sumProducts`
  FROM invoice_products
 GROUP BY invoiceID;
```