# MSQL sum month values plus group concat

Tags: mysql, subquery, sum, group-concat

Need help on a query to sum all values by month grouped by comma

Trying:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( (
    SELECT SUM( price ) 
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY MONTH( date ) )
    )
FROM sales
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but returning: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

group_concat alone won't help cause I need the sum of the values by month.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.totprice) 
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(price) as totprice
  FROM sales
  GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) a;
```

Note that you will get max 12 values, since any different years are merged. You probably want to add an `ORDER BY` in the subquery to get the months in a defined order in the result.

Comment: Thanks, but returning a strange value: [BLOB - 13 B]

Comment: OK, MySQL thinks the result is binary for some reason. What is the data type of the price column? Change first row to `SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(a.totprice) as CHAR)` and you will get text.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. It was float and tried varchar as well, but your solution worked! Thanks

Comment: Great. You will probably not need the `CAST` in the normal query, phpmyadmin seems to create the blob problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133936/using-group-concat-in-phpmyadmin-will-show-the-result-as-blob-3b