# MySql Fetching comma separated primary key in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch primary key of all rows of one table in a single query.

I implement it using query --

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS ids
FROM tbl_facebook_users
WHERE facebook_user_id
IN ( 336120419901063, 10205028697461204 )
```

It is giving result as:

**Result :-**

```
ids
-----------
[BLOB - 4B]
```

What is the solution to implement this feature and get correct result??

Comment: What is the type of `id` field

Comment: Problem Solved : ------  select CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(id) USING utf8) as ids  from tbl_facebook_users   

It bydefault separate ids by comma ','

Answer (score 0):

With the reference to this post : [using group_concat in PHPMYADMIN will show the result as [BLOB - 3B]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133936/using-group-concat-in-phpmyadmin-will-show-the-result-as-blob-3b)

```
CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT( id SEPARATOR  ',' ) USING 'utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

use this 
**Show BLOB contents**
and don't use SEPARATOR in your query if you want SEPARATOR like ',' cause in the MySQL by default SEPARATOR  is ','

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by using following query :

select CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(id) USING utf8) as ids  from tbl_facebook_users

It bydefault separate ids by comma ','

If you want to use any other separator (say ';') use it as --

select CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ';' ) USING utf8) as ids  from tbl_facebook_users